# How to split merged/glued words with no delimiter using R

Tags: r, text-mining, gsub, rvest, strsplit

I'm scraping text keywords from this article page using rvest in R using the code below:

```
#install.packages("xml2") # required for rvest
library("rvest") # for web scraping
library("dplyr") # for data management

#' start with get the link for the web to be scraped
page <- read_html("https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1877042810004568")
keyW <- page %>% html_nodes("div.Keywords.u-font-serif") %>% html_text() %>% paste(collapse = ",")
```

And it gave me:

```
> keyW    
[1] "KeywordsPhysics curriculumTurkish education systemfinnish education systemPISAphysics achievement"
```

After removing the word "Keywords" and anything before it from the string using this line of code:

```
keyW <- gsub(".*Keywords","", keyW)
```

The new keyW is:

```
[1] "Physics curriculumTurkish education systemfinnish education systemPISAphysics achievement"
```

However, my desired output is this list:

```
[1] "Physics curriculum" "Turkish education system" "finnish education system" "PISA" "physics achievement"
```

How should I tackle this? I think this boils down to:

1. how to properly scrape the keywords from the website
2. how to properly split the string

Thanks

Comment: Please make your examples reproducible; R code to load packages is missing: `library(xml2)`, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You get the expected output directly if you use `span` tag to extract the words.

```
library(rvest)
page %>%  html_nodes("div.Keywords span") %>% html_text()

#[1] "Physics curriculum"       "Turkish education system" "finnish education system"
#[4] "PISA"                     "physics achievement"
```